# How to do a SUM instead of a UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have the following query to get two different counts:

```
  select count(*)  
  from title_title where tv_show_id is null
union
  select count(distinct tv_show_id) 
  from title_title where tv_show_id is not null
```

Is there a simple way to add the two together within SQL instead of doing the addition outside of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As both queries use the same table, you could convert the `where` clauses to `case` expressions within the aggregate functions, and then add the results. Note that `count`, like most aggregate functions ignores `null`s, so this can be done relatively neatly:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN tv_show_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) +
       COUNT(DISTINCT tv_show_id) -- nulls are ignored anyway
FROM   title_title
```

Comment: nice and simple, better than my answer :)

Comment: Good idea with the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse the `MSSQL` answer, but I believe you should be able to do this (or something very similar) in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  (COUNT(tt.*) + COUNT(tt2.tv_show_id)) AS Total
FROM    title_title tt
    JOIN title_title tt2 ON tt.tv_show_id = tt2.tv_show_id
WHERE   tt.tv_show_id IS NULL
    AND tt2.tv_show_id IS NOT NULL
```

Perform a `JOIN` back to the table, grabbing the count from each (`tt.*` and `tt2.tv_show_id`) and summing the counts that way.